# Is using Shared Preferences for storing user data reliable?

Tags: android, data-storage

Will the data still be there after the user restarts his / her phone or changes SIM / battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The data is persistent. Unless the user 'restores it to factory defaults'

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences are stored in the phone's internal memory, not the SD card.
They won't be erased by a reboot/battery change either.